# SQL Statement execution successful but not committing in python script

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I've got an SQL statement that executes just fine when I run it in SSMS:

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)='' SELECT @sql += ' Drop table ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '; ' FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' Exec Sp_executesql @sql
```

Basically just drops all tables in the database. However, when I go to try and execute this in a python script, it succeeds, but the tables don't actually end up dropping. I'm establishing a connection to my database with an account that has permissions to do so, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Here's my engine creation and the part of the code where I may be doing something wrong:

```py
engine_azure2 = create_engine(conn_str2,echo=True)
conn2 = engine_azure2.connect()


deleteQuery = text("DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)='' SELECT @sql += ' Drop table ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '; ' FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' Exec Sp_executesql @sql")
conn2.execute(deleteQuery)
```

I've also tried encapsulating it inside of a BEGIN...END, no luck.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`pool_reset_on_return` parameter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.pool_reset_on_return) to `create_engine`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning wow, thank you! I believe ```engine_azure2 = create_engine(conn_str2,echo=True, pool_reset_on_return='commit')``` did the trick! If you want to write up an answer, I'll accept it. Also I must admit, I don't fully understand why that worked.

Comment: it's just that some drivers don't use autocommit, meaning the changes don't get persisted when the statement finish, while SSMS by default commits

Comment: FYI, using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.